# How to add specific time in recycling application pool through IIS and it will show in event logs?

Tags: performance, iis, web-applications, pool, event-viewer

I wanted to test an application app pool in recycling specific time. I already configure it in IIS settings but still upon checking on event viewer recycling time is not showing. Is there anybody can help me with it?

Comment: can you share some code?

Answer (score 0):

Did you see the configuration in applicationhost.config like this?

```
  <add name="application pool">
                <recycling>
                    <periodicRestart>
                        <schedule>
                            <clear />
                            <add value="13:43:00" />
                        </schedule>
                    </periodicRestart>
                </recycling>
            </add>
```

Have you checked whether the PID of your application pool get changed after the scheduled times?

To troubleshooting this issue, we need to check this is an application pool recycle issue or an event log issue.

IIS will not write recycle event log until you enable Scheduled time  for recycling event log.
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your response and I already did some troubleshooting and tried to do what you send to me like the screenshot you had. I will try it again.

Comment: @roxannedelier Looking forward to hear from you. Please check whether application get recycled or not first.